# How do I *fully* specify a different '.git' dir

Tags: git

If you specify GIT_DIR=".git2" it will only specify this as relative to the current directory.  And in this case it will not do the "search up until the first parent dir that contains a '.git2'" protocol as it does with the default '.git'.

Also if you specify a full path like /home/me/project/.git2 it will not add and commit files to a path in the repository relative to the location of the '.git2'.

So the question - is there a way to substitute the folder name git uses to some other name than '.git' and have all other aspects of the protocol work exactly the same way as they do with the default '.git' name ???

Comment: Why do you want this? A little context might help us a little.

Comment: In general want to know unprejudiced :)

Comment: But: in this case I have a private internal and a public repo and want to keep them both in sync and separate, yet both rooted in the same tree.  Ideal would be if one could assign "culled" subsets of a specific repository so when a "public" user accessed it it woudl only include data from *specific* branches and not the full history, but as git compacts things into non branch specific bundles containing all the history of everything since the inception of the repository this is apparently not possible in git at present.

Comment: FWIW, I would just use submodules. Have your submodule be your public repository and have the parent module be the real repository. This would be much easier in my opinion.

Comment: looked at that but both trees have the same root and structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this for a particular repository:

```
export GIT_DIR=/home/me/project/.git2
export GIT_WORK_TREE="$(dirname "${GIT_DIR}")"
git ...
```

or:

```
git --git-dir=/home/me/project/.git2 --work-tree=/home/me/project ...
```

If you want to change the default name of the Git directory everywhere, you can do something convoluted like this:

```
git() (
    # if GIT_DIR is set, honor it
    [ -z "${GIT_DIR+set}" ] || { command git "$@"; exit $?; }

    # find GIT_DIR
    GIT_DIR=$(
        : "${GIT_DIR_NAME=.git2}"
        while true; do
            [ -d "${GIT_DIR_NAME}" ] && {
                printf '%s\n' "${PWD%/}/${GIT_DIR_NAME}"
                exit 0
            }
            [ "$(pwd -P)" != / ] || {
                echo "fatal: Not a git repository" >&2
                exit 1
            }
            cd .. || exit 1
        done
    ) || exit 1

    # set GIT_WORK_TREE based on GIT_DIR if it is not already set
    [ -n "${GIT_WORK_TREE+set}" ] || {
        GIT_WORK_TREE=$(dirname "${GIT_DIR}") || exit 1
    }

    # run the actual git with the discovered directories
    GIT_DIR=${GIT_DIR} GIT_WORK_TREE=${GIT_WORK_TREE} command git "$@"
)
```

With the above, when you run `git foo` it'll search for `.git2` instead of `.git`.  For the working directory, it'll use the directory containing `.git2`.

Comment: Thanks - I guess scripting is what to do.

Answer (score 1):

> So the question - is there a way to substitute the folder name git uses to some other name than '.git' and have all other aspects of the protocol work exactly the same way as they do with the default '.git' name ???

I don't think there's any way to do that.  Why don't you set the full path to `.git2` as `GIT_DIR` and also set a full path for `GIT_WORK_DIR`?  The rules about how `GIT_WORK_DIR` and `GIT_DIR` determine the top of your working directory and your git directory are complex and easy to get wrong.  If you set both (and set them to absolute paths) then you typically have many fewer problems.